# EF Core 6 - Multiple Tables Based Off 1 Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I've seen very old answers relating to this (and conflicting answers), but I am wondering if it's possible to use 1 base entity to create multiple tables in EF Core.

My specific scenario is this: I have about 110 tables, and I need to preserve the data after they are "deleted".

However, because there are a number of 1-to-1 relationships, I cannot set a delete flag to mark the table as "deleted". I would like to have an "Archive" table for each entity, and on Delete in my repository I would find the entity from the original table, add it to the archive table, then delete it from the original table.

However it seems like EF Core creates tables based solely on the classes the models are themselves and not by the tables that are defined.

Is there any way to get around this without needing to create a separate "archive" model for my 110 existing model classes?

Comment: "and I need to preserve the data after they are "deleted"" - why not use temporal-tables?

Comment: Assuming that you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, you could take a look at [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16). I haven't used them but they look relevant to your use case.

Comment: Well I will need to use these "deleted" tables for lookup and reporting, so I'm not sure if temporal tables will solve my issue there.